# SSH public key authentication

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Is there any possibility to change the authentication method of an SSH user user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx from password authentication to public-key authentication, without knowing its current password?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the authentication method (password or public-key authentication) two things must happen:

- "user" must come up with a password or generate a key pair;
- the password hash or the public key must be configured in the server ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") "user" wants to connect to.

If you are an admin (root) of the server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) you can ask "user" to send you his public key and put it in the right place and you don't need to know the password of "user".

If you are "user", you need to connect to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" at least once with your password so that you can upload your public key.
Here I am assuming that the SSH server is using the default OpenSSH configuration where the "authorized_keys" file of each user is in the user's home directory, under his/her control.

If you then want to "force" the authentication method to "public key", an admin will need to edit the configuration of the SSH server to disable password authentication (either for everybody or just for "user").

Comment: thanks, this is the answer that I am looking for

Comment: Glad I could help. In that case, I'd appreciate if you could "accept" my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a help post about the ssh config.

https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5

You can disable password authentication by using:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

If your interested how ssh is working. You can use *ssh -v user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx* to use verbose mode. That sometimes helps with debugging.

Comment: This would probably be used, though, by a user who wanted to bypass a password prompt if password authentication was checked by the server before public-key authentication. It doesn't *prevent* a user from using password authentication, since the user is voluntarily turning it off. The "without knowing its current password" part of the question implies you want a change in the server to prevent password authentication from being an option.

Comment: Ok so if you are on a linux server and want to change access settings, you can look into the /etc/security/access.conf file. But that has nothing to do with ssh. The /etc/ssh/sshd_config file contains a PasswordAuthentication setting, you can change to: no. But that can not differ from user to user, but is a 'global' setting. It would be helpful if you could specify your environment.